# How can we compare exponential values using awk

Tags: awk

The input file looks like.

```
abc=1.01
abc=0.99
abc=2.1
abc=0.9
abc=2.23e-07
abc=1.22
```

I would like to print the value of abc is less than 1.0. So that output should look like.

```
abc=0.99
abc=0.9
abc=2.23e-07
```

However, when I run the code, the last line is absent. Tried as

```
awk -F '=' '{if($2<1) print $0}' file
```

awk --version

```
GNU Awk 3.1.7
```

Comment: @msp9011 `bc` an option?

Comment: @msp9011: I'm missing the point probably, but what's wrong with your attempt. You seem to be getting the output as needed?

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't this script doing what you want? 2.23e-07 is less than 2? Also, you can simplify the script to `awk -F '=' '$2<1' file`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20684512

Comment: @Inian i'm getting only first two lines of expected output, not the third line.

Comment: @Sparhawk , 2.23e-07 is 0.00000023.. which is less than 1. and it's not printing with the provided code.

Comment: @msp9011: Post the `awk` version you tested this on? It seems to work on GNU awk just fine. May be can you try `$2+0 < 1`

Comment: You're not in a locale where `,` is the decimal separator, are you? Try `LC_ALL=C awk -F '=' '$2<1' file`

Comment: @finswimmer thanks... it worked with `gawk`

Comment: Ah right got it. I thought you were posting the actual output, not the expected output. I've edited to clarify. It works fine for me too.

Answer (score 0):

I think it wll work once you rewrite abc=2.23e-07 to abc=2.23*e-07.

Comment: You should probably test it too...